# PHP Ajax - How to condition if modal will popup?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to make a condition if the page will now load a modal? so far I have this button and it will submit it to the `home.php` which will trigger the modal. but the problem is i need to refresh the page before the modal will popup.

now what i need is to auto display the modal without refreshing the page so condition will do this or an auto refresh

P.S I already have the solution for this but the page was refreshing ever 3 seconds and my pc lags so it is not a practical way of doing.

here is my button whch will trigger the modal on `onclick.php`

```
$.confirm({
type: 'red',
theme: 'material',
title: 'Are you sure you want to make an announcement?',
content:'<strong>Announcement Info:</strong> ' + addInfo,
buttons: {
    Yes: {
        btnClass: 'btn-green',
        action: function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "announcement.php",
                data: {
                    addInfo: addInfo
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {


//THIS TRIGGER THE MODAL
window.location.replace("change-password.php");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);

                }

            });

        }

    }
```

and here is my trigger modal which is on `home.php`

so when that button was pressed this page will automatically load modal.
as ive said earlier here is my solution but the page was refreshing every 3 seconds so it is not a good idea.

```
    <script>

THIS REFRESHED THE PAGE EVERY 3 SECONDS BUT IT IS NOT A PRACTICAL CODE

// function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
//   setTimeout("location.reload(false);",timeoutPeriod);
// }

// window.onload = timedRefresh(3000);

function timedRefreshIfNoCookie(timeoutPeriod, cookieName) {
    var cookies = document.cookie;
    if (cookies.indexOf(' '+cookieName+'=1;') < 0) {
        document.cookie = cookieName+'=1';
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, timeoutPeriod);
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    timedRefreshIfNoCookie(5000, 'refreshed');

}   

//THIS WILL TRIGGER THE MODAL 
 document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='block';

</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to put your code into a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Store temporary data in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` or `cookie`. Then execute your condition.

```
if(yourCondition){

   window.sessionStorage("showModel","true");

}

//reload page

location.reload();
```

Every time load the page, Call the popup function just before your `</body>` as following..

```
if(window.sessionStorage("showModel") == "true"){

    $("#yourModelId").modal('show');

    //reset value to false to prevent continuous model popup 
    window.sessionStorage("showModel","false");

}
```